# is_page(id) not working for blog page

Tags: php, blog-page

I am trying to add a css file specific to 3 pages using the `is_page(postid)` for a WordPress website in the `functions.php`

```
 if (is_page(1) || is_page(2) || is_page(3) ) {
           echo "<script>console.log('insideIf');</script>";
           wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_template_directory_child() . path);  
        }
```

So considering 1,2 and 3 are the ids of the pages, the pages with the ids 2 and 3 are logging the message in the console and loading the css file whereas `is_page(1)` does not respond.

I tried changing it to `is_page('1')` or `is_single()` or `is_single(1)`. The page that is not getting detected is a blog page and i even tried with the title `is_page('blog')`.

Ps. Cross checked the id many times, so I am definitely not using the wrong id.

Comment: What hook do you use with this if statement?

Comment: If page with ID `1` is set as static posts page (Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading) try to use `is_home()`. Look at [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page you’re trying to check is set as Page for posts, then `is_page` conditional won’t be true.

In such case you should check if [`is_home`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/).

Why? All these conditional tags are based on global `wp_query`. For page that is set as page for posts (home of your blog), the global query doesn’t contain singular page - it contains list of blog posts.

Comment: Thank you. That worked!

Answer (score 2):

The conditional `is_page` is mapped to the [`is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_page/) method of the `wp_query` class. As you can see in the source a couple of things are tested.

First if the method does not apply to the object that is passed (for instance because it is not a `wp_query` instance), it returns false.

Then the [queried object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_queried_object/) is retrieved. This gets either the data for a page/post or, if the query is for an archive, data for that specific archive. Note that this method does nothing with the page ID that you have called `is_page` with. It retrieves the queried object regardless of that.

Next it tests the queried object against the page ID (or page name, or post title) that you passed. This is where it goes wrong in your case. The queried object is a blog archive, so it does not have a page ID in the context of this conditional test. As a result `is_page` returns false.

Most likely `is_home` will do the trick, because that tests for the main blog archive. Otherwise you may need a more complicated set of tests to target this page.

Comment: it worked using is_home(), Thank you for the nice explanation!